# Obtener cadena de conexion SqlServer 2008 SIN Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms

Tengo un VPS con Windows Server 2012 y con SqlServer ya instalado. Y desarrollé un Sitio Web con conexión a BDD en mi PC local. La cadena de conexión que utilizo, la generé con Visual Studio al conectar una tabla desde la misma IDE.

En mi VPS **no puedo instalar otros programas**, existe una forma de obtener la Cadena de Conexión, sólo con el SqlServer o SqlManager?

Comment: Tu VPS debería proporcionarte los datos de acceso a tu cuenta del sqlserver, y para construir la cadena de conexion simplemente pásate por [connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Al VPS entro por escritorio remoto al Windows Server Instalado...No tiene Control Panel o algo así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener la cadena de conexión contra una base de datos sin necesidad de VS o similar puedes crear un fichero con extensión .udl y abrirlo. Este archivo tiene esta apariencia: [image: Archivo UDL]

En la pestaña de proveedor puedes cambiar entre SQL Server (por defecto), OLE db y en general los tipos de BDD de los que tengas los drivers instalados (los OLE vienen por defecto en MS)

Una vez insertados los parámetros de conexión, pulsas aceptar y después botón derecho sobre el archivo y abrir con bloc de notas (o notepad++, a tu gusto) y obtendrás algo similar a esto:
[image: Cadena de conexión]

Espero que te sirva y sea lo que buscas.

Saludos!!

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!, esos si, hice conexión con USER/PASS y no muestra el campo de contraseña. así que a la cadena de conexión le agregué Password=**** (el password).

Comment: De nada!!. Por favor marca la respuesta como válida, así otro que tenga la misma duda lo verá